# React - what is the right way to sum the value of object by its type and then setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have below data

```
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Tim",
      score: [
        {
          score: 4,
          type: "communication"
        },
        {
          score: 4,
          type: "delivery"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Ken",
      score: [
        {
          score: 2,
          type: "communication"
        },
        {
          score: 4,
          type: "delivery"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

and below object variable at the beginning

```
      let typeTotalScore = {
        communication: 0,
        delivery: 0
      };
```

and useState hook

```
  const [scoreByType, setScoreByType] = useState({});
```

I want to loop through `data` and get below result and then use `setScoreByType(typeTotalScore)`.

```
{
  communication: 6,
  delivery: 8
}
```

How should I do it in `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let typeTotalScore = {
        communication: 0,
        delivery: 0
      };

     // some looping?

     setScoreByType(typeTotalScore)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combine all score array into one. Then use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for sum the value

```js
const data = [ { id: 1, name: "Tim", score: [ { score: 4, type: "communication" }, { score: 4, type: "delivery" } ] }, { id: 2, name: "Ken", score: [ { score: 2, type: "communication" }, { score: 4, type: "delivery" } ] } ];


const res =  data.flatMap(a=> a.score).reduce((acc,{type,score})=>{
   acc[type] = acc[type] || 0; //check the key and assigning the value 
   acc[type] = acc[type] + score // sum the previous score with new
   return acc
},{})

console.log(res)
```